# Optimizing Indexes in MySql table

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, database-optimization

I have a table in mysql database which will have large amount of records soon, so I want to add some indexes to have better performance with my queries. My queries have variation of 4 fields, ( template_id (int), data(text), state(int), hub_id(int) ). And non of these 4 fields are NOT my primary key field for the table. I have these 3 types of where clause in my queries for this table:

```
where state = XXX
where template_id = XXX AND state = YYYY
where hub_id = XXX AND data = 'YYYY' AND template_id = ZZZZ
```

What is the best approach for making indexes for this table which has 4 columns with different combination of where clauses? Should I create 3 seperated Indexes for int fields and one FullText for data(text) field? I assume the best practice is to create one index for each where clause combination, but in that case, How should I deal with data field which is a text field, is that good to put index on text field?

Thanks for your advises

Comment: When asking for query optimization help, you should always post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all table(s) you are querying.

Comment: I mentioned it is just one table! and those are queries related to that specific table!

Comment: Sorry, that comment does not include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`.

Comment: Show us a fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) or some SHOW CREATE TABLE output. It makes a difference, as scaisEdge found out when you surprised him when you revealed the datatype of a column. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are these only samples?  If so, the answer gets messier than scaisEdge's answer.

Comment: No, they are not sample, Could you please explain more? @RickJames

Answer (score 2):

looking to your where  typical condition you should use  just 3 index  with the last 2 as composite

```
 idx1(state)

 idx2(template_id, state)

 idx3(hub_id,data,  template_id)  or  idx3(hub_id,  template_id, data)
```

depending on the cardinality of the data and template_id

in this way the 3 indexes don't interfer one with the others and shoul be used  properly by the sql optiminizer .

Remember that when the sql optimizer don't choose the index you thinks is better  you can force the choice  using FORCE or USE

Comment: thanks for the answer, data field is a text field, is that ok to use text fields as INDEX ?

Comment: no text is not valid  because there is a limit for the index   key length .. but you could avoid the data column  .. the idx3 second option  don't interfer with the others

Comment: Yes, either of those idx3's makes a nice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index . Note that even `text` can have its prefix indexed, which would help with the four-character literal of `data='YYY'`. You'd have to pay attention to EXPLAIN output to verify the desired access path is actually being used. Switching to a very long VARCHAR might make getting the query right a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(state, template_id)  -- (in this order) handles the first two
INDEX(hub_id, data, template_id)  -- in any order handles 3rd
```

For further discussion see [*my cookbook*](http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: I would just add that the field order for the third index has the column with the LEAST # of records in first position.  Ex: State vs Zip code within a state... the ZIP code would be the smaller result set to plow through.

Comment: @DRapp - it is a common myth that cardinality matters in ordering the columns of a BTree index.  It does not matter.  Exactly the same number of rows are ultimately scanned, regardless of the order of columns.